# htaccess rewrite rule - no extension and slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am not familiar with .htaccess file so excuse me if my question is a little absurd.

When I request for

```
localhost/mydomain/blog.php
```

I want to have a url of this form:

```
localhost/mydomain/blog/
```

My website directory looks like that:

[image]

The .htaccess file includes the following:

Remove .php extension

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>        
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

With this link

```
<a href="blog">Blog</a>
```

The url is:

```
localhost/createforweb_1.1/blog
```

But I want to add a trailing slash, so if I add these lines in htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/createforweb_1.1/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I get this error:

```
The requested URL /blog/.php was not found on this server.
```

I'm sure is very simple but I have a little experience in .htaccess rewrite!

#### LATEST .htaccess file (whole file)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks
# Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
 RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

I just created a folder for every page, moved the files inside and renamed them into index.php. The new directory tree looks like that:

[image]

Now I request blog folder and blog/index.php is loading. URL becomes createforweb.gr/blog/

Is this an acceptable solution, or it will create problems in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you abubhava! Although blog.php exists in the website directory, I now get the following error message: "The requested URL /blog.php was not found on this server."

Comment: THat is most likely because of the other trailing slash rule. Let me suggest you something for that as well.

Comment: Still the same error! I have tried many combinations but I don't know what exactly I am doing..

Comment: Post your latest .htaccess in your question. Also I didn't get what is `createforweb_1.1`? Is hat your DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: I have edited my question with the new .htaccess. createforweb_1.1 is my DOCUMENT_ROOT. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok and now the error you're getting is `The requested URL /blog.php was not found on this server.` **INSTEAD OF** `The requested URL /blog/.php was not found on this server.` right?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just deployed above code on my webserver and everything worked fine. `/blog` became `/blog/` and internally it loaded `/blog.php`. Can't guess what is causing problem for you. Make sure above .htaccess is in right under createforweb_1.1 and you have `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` and `RewriteEngine On` lines at the top.

Comment: .htaccess is right under createforweb_1.1 folder and the .htaccess file looks like the one I edited again. The same error occurs! How can not be able to load the existing blog.php file?

Comment: Hmm as you can see the erro you;re getting that `/blog.php` not found for a URI in your browser `/blog` which is becoming `/blog/` first in the browser. All that means that rules are working fine because it is trying to load `/blog.php` correctly. Can you directly enter `/blog.php` in the browser and see what you get.

Comment: When I enter "http://localhost/createforweb_1.1/blog.php" it gets the right page (of course the url remains /blog.php)

Comment: Ah you have `/createforweb_1.1/` in your URL. That means it is NOT DOCUMENTR_ROOT. I have asked this specifically and you wrote that it is root :)

Comment: Make sure my edited .htaccess is 1 level above `createforweb_1.1` which is your `$DOCUMENTR_ROOT` and then enter this URL in browser: `http://localhost/createforweb_1.1/blog`

Comment: I thought .htaccess file should be at the same level as index.php. I uploaded the files here "http://createforweb.gr" and it does not load css files and then creates an infinite loop!

Comment: Does `http://localhost/createforweb_1.1/blog` load `blog.php` or it still throws 404? Once that is resolved we'll resolve css problems easily.

Comment: http://localhost/createforweb_1.1/blog still throws the following error: "The requested URL /blog.php was not found on this server." I use the .htaccess file from HTML5-boilerplate (http://html5boilerplate.com/), so the .htaccess file contains other rules too. I don't know if something else affects what we are trying to do.

Comment: As much as I want to help you I think it won't be possible without looking directly at your server. If you can provide me a temporary access to your server pls write an email to: anubhavas[at]gmail[dot]com

Comment: I just came up with a solution (check "createforweb.gr"). I edited my question. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: If you have only handful of php files to manage then this is an acceptable work around. However if you can have lots of php files in future then it will be same # of directories plus same # of index.php files inside them which will create some clutter for you to manage.